# checking if an array is a subset of another array? (c++)

Tags: c++, arrays

The desired idea is: to enter a set size & members, if the size is valid, enter 1st subset (A), if A is valid subset, do same with 2nd subset (B).

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    while (true) {
        int i = 0;
        int k = 0;
        int * set;
        int setSize;
        cout << "Input size of set" << endl;
        cin >> setSize;
        if (setSize <= 0) {
            cout << "Invalid size!" << endl;
        }
        else {
            set = new int[setSize];
            for (int i = 0; i < setSize; i++)
            {
                cout << "set[" << i + 1 << "]=";
                cin >> set[i];
            }
            int * A;
            int sizeA;
            cout << "Input size of subset A" << endl;
            cin >> sizeA;
            if (sizeA <= 0 || sizeA > setSize) {
                cout << "Invalid size for a subset, please try again!" << endl;
            }
            else {
                A = new int[sizeA];
                cout << "Input members of A" << endl;
                for (int i = 0; i < sizeA; i++)
                {
                    cout << "A[" << i + 1 << "]=";
                    cin >> A[i];
                }
                for (i = 0; i < sizeA; i++)
                {
                    for (k = 0; k < setSize; k++)
                    {
                        if (A[i] == set[k])
                            break;
                    }
                    if (k == setSize) {
                        return 0;
                    }
                    else{
                        int * B;
                        int sizeB;
                        cout << "Input size of subset B" << endl;
                        cin >> sizeB;
                        if (sizeB <= 0 || sizeB > setSize) {
                            cout << "Invalid size for a subset, please try again!" << endl;
                        }
                        else {
                            B = new int[sizeB];
                            cout << "Input members of B" << endl;
                            for (int i = 0; i < sizeB; i++)
                            {
                                cout << "B[" << i + 1 << "]=";
                                cin >> B[i];
                            }
                            for (i = 0; i < sizeB; i++)
                            {
                                for (k = 0; k < setSize; k++)
                                {
                                    if (B[i] == set[k])
                                        break;
                                }
                                if (k == setSize) {
                                    cout << "Not a subset, please try again!" << endl;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then I would like to convert 'em to bit strings and perform some operations...

Comment: there is nothing wrong, unless you tell us what is wrong ;). Does it compile? Does it crash? Does it produce correct results?

Comment: Please ask specifically where you are facing a problem? Also in case of any errors/bugs please specify them.

Comment: Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It sounds like a practice to learn. In this case, I encourage you tu use a debugger: it is a really useful tool to find bug, _but_ also a great tool to learn how code works (run step by step your program to observe how variables evolve

Comment: OK I don't mean bugs, but logic. Not every (A) I enter is correctly defined to be subset. E.g. if a set is {1,2,3,4,5} and A is {3,4,6} it doesn't break

Comment: To repeat Garf365, a debugger enables you to **observe how variables evolve**. That said, your program is far too nested for other people to take the time to find the problem. You mixed input/output with basic functionality and use far less if-conditions in if-conditions. You want to do some basic input, then arrive at a position where you are free of anything but your infinity loop, with the necessary vectors, and then you feed them into a function. If you do that, we can directly help you with that isolated function. Btw, you write that it's not a bug, but that is exactly what a bug is.

Comment: First, unrelated issues belong in different functions. Here: Separate *filling the arrays* from *checking for subset*. Nobody is interested in your input routine. Do not even post it here (but, for example, have two arrays filled with hard-coded mock data).

Answer (score 2):

Rather than spoon-feed a complete answer, I'll give some advice on how to approach programming problems such as this.

Firstly, don't write everything in `main()`.  Instead, declare a function that operates on suitable data structures and returns an appropriate result.  For this function it's clear that the result should be a `bool` - true if the second array is a subset of the first, otherwise false:

```
bool is_subset(std::vector<int> a, std::vector<int> b);
```

I chose `vector` because that carries its size around with it, making it easier to work with.

Now we have that, we can start to test it (yes, we write the tests first - obviously they will fail until we implement `is_subset()`, but that's how we know the tests are any good).  The simplest test I can think of is, "is an empty set a subset of itself?":

```
int main()
{
    assert(is_subset({}, {}));
}
```

Write enough code for this test to pass.  It could be as simple as

```
bool is_subset(std::vector<int> a, std::vector<int> b)
{
    return a == b;
}
```

That's obviously not complete, but that's okay.  It's enough to satisfy the tests we have so far, but we need to add more tests.  So, go ahead and write another test:

```
int main()
{
    // empty set is a subset of itself
    assert(is_subset({}, {}));

    // empty set is a subset of a non-empty set
    assert(is_subset({1}, {}));
}
```

And make it pass:

```
bool is_subset(std::vector<int> a, std::vector<int> b)
{
    using std::begin;
    using std::end;

    return std::includes(begin(a), end(a),  begin(b), end(b));
}
```

There are a few more basic tests - a trivial set is always a subset of itself, and no non-empty set is a subset of an empty set, for instance.

Then you can start getting more creative with your tests.  As the list of tests grows, you are building up a description of what you require of your function that's much clearer than your natural-language prose (e.g. what do you mean by 'set'?  Can it have repeated elements?).

Once you have a working, tested function, then you can add the niceties of input (from stdin, or from command arguments) and output (to stdout, or as the exit code).  Note that I've shown several means of input and output - with separate functions, you can mix and match different I/O functions with your algorithm according to need.

You can also look at further improvements, such as using templates so you can use types such as `long` or `std::string` in place of `int` (but make sure you're aware of the problems with floating-point equality before trying `double` or `float`).

---

Here's what my full program looks like once I've implemented a few tests:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

bool is_subset(std::vector<int> a, std::vector<int> b);

int main()
{
    // empty set is a subset of itself
    assert(is_subset({}, {}));

    // empty set is a subset of a non-empty set
    assert(is_subset({1}, {}));

    // no non-empty set is a subset of an empty set
    assert(!is_subset({}, {1}));

    // Two different non-empty sets
    assert(!is_subset({0}, {1}));

    // Proper subset
    assert(is_subset({1, 2, 3}, {2}));

    // Unordered proper subset
    assert(is_subset({1, 3, 2}, {2}));

    // All values in subset must be in superset
    assert(!is_subset({1, 2, 3}, {2, 2}));
    assert(is_subset({1, 2, 2, 3}, {2, 2}));
}


bool is_subset(std::vector<int> a, std::vector<int> b)
{
    using std::begin;
    using std::end;

    // The includes() algorithm requires sorted inputs
    std::sort(begin(a), end(a));
    std::sort(begin(b), end(b));
    return std::includes(begin(a), end(a),  begin(b), end(b));
}
```

---

A couple of other observations, in passing:

- Become familiar with the C++ Standard Library.  Notice that by using `vector` I don't need to manage memory with `new[]` and `delete[]`, and by using functions from `<algorithm>` I have saved much time reimplementing standard transformations - and the code becomes much clearer, too.
- Avoid memory management where possible - prefer standard collections where you can, smart pointer objects otherwise, and raw C-style pointers only when they cannot be avoided.  And always clean up the memory you allocate, even if the program is about to exit.  Not only does this make it easier to use tools such as Valgrind to learn about your program's correctness, it also enables re-use of your function in bigger programs.

Comment: Is an array a subset of another array? We can answer that question in terms of templates and the < inequality operation. But that's more for an intermediate level programmer. A beginner should just get something running with members constrained to be integers.

Comment: Yes, I was going to mention at the end that it can be parameterized as a template, but either forgot or ran out of time.  You're right that it's more advanced than is ready for the questioner, though!

Comment: @Malcolm - which `<` operator?  `std::set<>::operator<` isn't a subset predicate (and can't be, if it's to represent a strict weak ordering, as one expects).

Comment: Conventionally, we supply '<' for ordering. So !(a < b) && !(b < a) is the equality test. To write a generic "is subset", sort the putative super-set, then search for each element of the putative set (if you sort it too you can   also handle duplicate elements).

Comment: Isn't that pretty much how `std::includes()` works? (modulo the searching, which is obviated by requiring the candidate subset be sorted with the same comparator; that also enables the use of forward iterators).

Comment: I'd guess. If you put the burden of sorting onto caller then you can use iterators. But then the function issubset becomes so trivial, and specialised that it effectively disappears. That's a common problem with programming.